# Dequeue immediately after starting threads fails

Tags: tensorflow

So I've been reading on how queuing and dequeuing works in tensorflow, and I've been playing around with making a filename queue and pulling from it.

Unfortunately I'm getting an error if I try dequeue immediately after starting the threads. Is there a reason for this? If I put in a 1 second sleep timer in, it will dequeue fine. If not, it sometimes works, but often will throw an exception (shown below code)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    filename_list = ['data_batch_{}.mat'.format(i+1) for i in range(5)]
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename_list)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        #time.sleep(1) # If I uncomment this it works
        for i in range(5):
            print(sess.run(filename_queue.dequeue()))

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

And the exception thrown:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-cf6ab7b71f22> in <module>()
     10         #time.sleep(1)
     11         for i in range(5):
---> 12             print(sess.run(filename_queue.dequeue()))
     13 
     14         coord.request_stop()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    331     try:
    332       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 333                          run_metadata_ptr)
    334       if run_metadata:
    335         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    571     try:
    572       results = self._do_run(handle, target_list, unique_fetches,
--> 573                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    574     finally:
    575       # The movers are no longer used. Delete them.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    646     if handle is None:
    647       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
--> 648                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
    649     else:
    650       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
    666         except KeyError:
    667           pass
--> 668       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
    669 
    670   def _extend_graph(self):

NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node input_producer_Dequeue:0: not found
```

Comment: Is the line `sess.run()` a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry. That causes a different error. I've edited it out.

Comment: Can you try to add `dequeue_op = filename_queue.dequeue()` before and then call `sess.run(dequeue_op)`?

Comment: That works. It runs now without faulting.

Comment: Don't know why you got the error though

Comment: I spoke too soon. Even with creating a dequeue op, it will fault sometimes if I try to run it directly after starting the threads. 
It's not a big deal for me to put in a sleep timer, as starting the threads only happens once.

Comment: If you can reproduce the error, consider reporting it as an issue on Tensorflow's GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for letting us know about this problem. I've filed a corresponding 
[GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2957), and prepared a fix, which should appear in the repository soon.

In the meantime, the following code should work, by creating a single `dequeue()` op before starting the session:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    filename_list = ['data_batch_{}.mat'.format(i+1) for i in range(5)]
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename_list)
    dequeued_t = filename_queue.dequeue()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        for i in range(5):
            print(sess.run(dequeued_t))

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: This works well. When I run my above code, it works roughly 50% of the time, this code runs fine 100% of the time.

Comment: I've since fixed the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2957), and if you try with TensorFlow 0.10 your existing code should now work. However, the code in my answer should be a bit more efficient because it doesn't create as many TensorFlow operations (so each `sess.run(dequeued_t)` does less work than `sess.run(filename_queue.dequeue())`).

Comment: Ah ok. Will my original code add a new op to the graph for each loop iteration? Also, your code creates the op before the session is created, does that make things faster too?

Comment: That's right. It's a subtle performance issue, because each time you create a new op, TensorFlow can't use cached information about previously executed graphs, and so it needs to do a bunch of graph analysis and protobuf serialization/deserialization, which can make the run-time of an individual step much longer (e.g. 100x for a simple step like this). Creating it before the session is started shouldn't make a performance difference, but as a style recommendation, I sometimes find it helps to create all ops before creating the session, to be surer that I'm not creating ops in the training loop